# Azure Mobile service InsertAsync Get Status

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am inserting into my Azure Mobileservice SQL-Database and it works fine but I would like to know if there is an error so I can correct it.

How do I get the status from the `InsertAsync` to see if it succeed or failed?

```c#
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
  "https://YOUR-DOMAIN.azure-mobile.net/",
  "YOUR-KEY"
);

static IMobileServiceTable<Product> productTable = MobileService.GetTable<Product>();

Product product = new Product { 
  name = NPDName.Text,
  description = NPDDescription.Text,
  price = NPDPriceExkl.Text,
  tax = NPDTax.Text,
  stock = NPDStock.Text,
  available = NPDCBAvailable.Checked,
  active = true
};

productTable.InsertAsync(product);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i get the status from the InsertAsync to see if it succeed or failed?

[`InsertAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554262.aspx) returns a `Task`. If you want to know it's status, you need to `await` on it. In case it fails, an exception will propagate:

```
public async Task InsertAsync()
{
    Product product = new Product
    { 
       name = NPDName.Text,
       description = NPDDescription.Text,
       price = NPDPriceExkl.Text,
       tax = NPDTax.Text,
       stock = NPDStock.Text,
       available = NPDCBAvailable.Checked,
       active = true
    };

    await productTable.InsertAsync(product);
}
```